# Date Issue when change Timezone to London

Tags: java, date

I have the code below:

```
package com.company.customer;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DateSample {
    private TimeZone GMT_TIMEZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    private SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat();
    private Date inputDate;
    private String dateInString = "2015-07-15";
    private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public void datePrint() {
        sdfDate.setTimeZone(GMT_TIMEZONE);
        sdfDate.applyPattern("EE-ddMMM");

        try {
            inputDate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("populateTabDates: ParseException");
        }

        String formatResults = sdfDate.format(inputDate);

        // Modify the return to cut down the weekday: Fri-20Aug => Fr-20Aug
        formatResults = formatResults.substring(0, 2) + formatResults.substring(3);

        System.out.println(formatResults);
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I set my PC to London timezone and change the PC hour to 8 or 9am. Then, the formatResults variable shows 14 instead of July 15; any thoughts?

Comment: You should always include a tag specifying what language you're using. (It seemed obvious enough in this case, so I added the "java" tag for you.)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. In addition, I'm working on a legacy code, so the getTimeZone("GMT"); is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't set the time zone for `formatter`, so that's whatever the system default time zone is.

So, you're parsing "2015-07-15" using the system default time zone. If that's London, you're parsed date is 2015-07-15T00:00:00+01 which is 2015-07-14T23:00:00Z. When you format that using the UTC time zone and just the date part, you're getting July 14th.

Put *both* formatters into the same time zone, basically, or you should expect a parse/format pair to "shift" the value. (This would be easier to see if you were also parsing and formatting the time of day.)

I'd also recommend using `UTC` as the name of the UTC time zone instead of `GMT`; the latter might confuse some people into thinking it's the UK time zone, which alternates between GMT and BST.